# Java.lang.NumberFormatException error in parsing , in double value

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I have a double value which needs to be formatted

```
NumberFormat dft = NumberFormat.getInstance(); 
dft.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);
dft.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.UP);
Double n= Double.parseDouble(dft.format(xyz)); //1,733.211
```

I cannot format it because it has  "," in it so how to remove it from `n`.

Comment: You don't need `Double.parseDouble` at all.

Comment: What is the value expected at the end for you ?

Comment: @azro I have double value with long digits after decimal place,  i need to trim it to 3 decimal places and save back to same variable

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `parse` method of `NumberFormat` class to parse the number first (if you want to have numeric value), e.g.:

```
Number number = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().parse("1,733.211");
System.out.println(number);
```

Once done, you can format it:

```
NumberFormat dft = NumberFormat.getInstance(); 
dft.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);
dft.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.UP);
System.out.println(dft.format(number));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming xyz is a String and you just want to remove the comma:

```
Double n= Double.parseDouble(dft.format(xyz.replaceAll("[^0-9.]", "")));
```

Comment: The number is a double, not a String. It would be possible, but redundant and only a workaround to convert to a String and then back to a Double.

Comment: thanks i have one more problem ,                            `NumberFormat nft=new DecimalFormat("#0.00");                                                                  
Double num1= 1.5215897010460924E24;String s1=String.valueOf(num1);Log.printLine(s);//1.5215897010460924E24
Log.printLine(nft.format(Double.parseDouble(s1)));//1521589701046092400000000.00 `    
 why am i getting such output ?

Comment: they are both equals, the first one is scientific notation format. Have a look at this for some example: https://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips-100019/34-java-text/2326-display-numbers-in-scientific-notation.html